# Terminal hangs after entering SSH password but can send command over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn

something seems to be weird on a ubuntu 22.04 computer.

trying to ssh in it, the authentication is working but my terminal is hanging after:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

And :

- luckily I can send command over ssh with `ssh user@ip 'command'`  even if commands displaying something back are not always working (actually hanging after `debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0`)
- Weirdly it seems as well that I can't access my webserver anymore on the ip of this computer.
- I can connect in sftp but cannot make any command to work as well.
- scp is blocking to `0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA` even for small files when trying to cp from the remote pc to my pc, the other ways seems to be working

Maybe important but i'm working over a vpn. The machine seems to be connecting well to the vpn as I can ping and do somethings. Reboot over ssh command didn't change anything.

If you have any idea - it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: It was probably a network issue, with a bad connection. Weird that the link was apparently working in one way,  but now it's working again.